# Need Help Understanding Eagle Ground Plane

Tags: eaglecad

I am creating a pcb board on eagle for a Texas Instruments boost converter and I am experimenting with the polygon feature. Through research on the web I have leaned how to create a ground plane throughout the board. However, I have some questions that I just cant seem to find the answers to online. My first question would be, do I have to connect the ground of my battery to the ground plane of my board? If so, how would I go about doing that? Secondly, if I connected my grounds to vias would that automatically pass through to the ground plane or no? I experimented with vias and the ground plane on my previous model and was not able to get it right. If you could please help me that would be great. I am sorry if these questions are stupid but I have no prior experience in electronics and am teaching myself as I go.

Thanks,
John

Comment: related: [Does a Ground plane in Eagle still need connections?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221974/does-a-ground-plane-in-eagle-still-need-connections)

Comment: If you want the ground plane to be connected to a net, assign that net in the plane's settings and re-generate, which counter intuitively is done with the ratsnest command or keystroke.  As to the question if your battery's lower voltage terminal *should be* connected to the ground plane, that would indeed often be the case but would ultimately be a question about your circuit which is unanswerable from the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is the following: Finish the entire route of the tracks of your circuit. Draw the copper polygon around the entire contour of your PCB. Then assign a net this must be gnd. Clicking on Ratsnets will generate your GND plane. Simply the connector (-) of your battery will be part of the GND plane. By placing the tracks they immediately go from Top to Bottom. You must see who will make your PCB and according to it take into account the minimum diameter of the vias, do this before advancing in the design.
If you are working with a Buck converter you must be very careful in the layout, you must comply with the manufacturer's recommendation. You must isolate the nodes most prone to noise within the circuit.